# Knockout auto click when the page became active

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use data-bind click for one my spans, but when I'm trying to do it, the function start when the page became active, and don't wait for user press.
Any idea why???

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 rate">{{rate}}
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-edit" data-bind="click: $root.edit($parent ,$index())"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times" data-bind="click: $root.delete($parent ,min)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass additional arguments to your click handler function need to wrap your function calls into anonymous functions:

```
<span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-edit" 
     data-bind="click: function () { $root.edit($parent ,$index()) }"></span>
<span class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times" 
     data-bind="click: function () { $root.delete($parent ,min) } "></span>
```

See also in the documentation: [Note 2: Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters)